# Apps Script response to an alert box could open a secondary alert box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've tried piecing together information I've found in other posts but have something slightly off.

When a user selects "Yes I am done!" from a drop down on tab named "Participant List" in G11, I want a message box to open with a Yes or No button. If they select No, G11 reverts back to "No - I am still working." (this is the part that's working). If they select "Yes I am done!" I want another message box to open to let them know what to expect next. Everything works except for Message 2. Thanks for any help!

I would also like this alert to show up on an iphone or ipad.
Here's the script I'm using:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Participant List' && e.range.columnStart==7 && e.value=='Yes I am done! ') {
    var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Message', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if(resp==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
      return; 
    }if (buttonPressed === ui.Button.Yes) {getUi().alert("Message 2");
      e.range.setValue('No - I am still working.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: buttonPressed is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of changes to the code but I can't complete it because I don't know where buttonPressed came from it's undefined with no additional explanation.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Participant List' && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == 'Yes I am done! ') {
    let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var resp = ui.alert('Message', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (resp == ui.Button.YES) { 
      return; 
      } else if (buttonPressed == ui.Button.Yes) {
      ui.alert("Message 2");
      e.range.setValue('No - I am still working.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The Button Pressed is the 1st message that pops up after they select "Yes I'm Done" in G11. If they select Yes, I want a 2nd message to appear with next steps. If they Select No in the pop up, I want G11 to revert back to "No I am still working" (which worked with my script). I just can't get the 2nd message to appear if they select Yes in the first message box.